# Friction of an object falling between two walls

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, angular-momentum, friction

I'm simplifying this problem into 2D for easier understanding.

Lets say we have 2 vertical walls separated by distance x. Inside these walls I place an object that is only slightly smaller than x in width. In the real world I can see an object catching on the sides and experiencing some friction, however how would I calculate the amount of friction force/energy? The bouncing between walls seems a little chaotic which leads me the the thinking that I can only get a worst case estimate of the friction - which is actually fine in my case.

I know the typical equation for friction is:

```
Ff = u x Fn
Ff = friction force
u = coefficient of friction
Fn = normal force
```

But my applying that equation to this problem has be stumped!

Comment: Take an average of many trials.

Comment: How would I go about calculating a single trial though? I've used methods like monte-carlo approximations in the past, but I'm stumped a few steps before that.

Comment: And you have already looked through the alternative probability distributions listed here I guess? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my issue here. The problem isn't the statistical analysis of multiple possible results. The problem is I'm unsure how to calculate the friction force.

Comment: While you could indeed model the friction force (vertical) to be proportional to the normal force (horizontal), also known as coulomb friction, it is hard to determine the normal force. The (intense) normal forces result from short impulses. Some would model the impulses as being infinitesimally short with a coefficient of restitution, but this method is mostly not accurate. The result is in fact very much determined by the compliance of the wall and the object, so I would suggest modeling either the ball or the wall as being compliant.

Comment: This is called an ill-defined problem. A well defined problem would be given by two parallel plates with a spring in-between which causes a well defined and (almost) distance independent normal force. Putting a rigid body between two rigid walls is not defined, unless you are willing to treat it as a continuum mechanics problem using a stress tensor for at least one of the walls or the body itself.

Comment: see [How does one calculate frictional force for an object sliding down a wall?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363703)

Comment: @sammygerbil the question you linked it helpful, the downvote however was a little unfair. Linking another question is great, downvoting because a question has already been asked, also OK. Down voting because a question has *since* been asked, not helpful.